# trying to store variable in a text file in python

Tags: python, file-io

```py
number = open("var.txt", "r")
num = number.setting_data.readlines()
number.close()

while True:
    employee_file = open("employess.txt", "w")
    employee_file.write("\nbot #" + str(num))
    employee_file.close()
    number = open("var.txt", "w")
    num = int(num)
    num += 1
    employee_file.write(str(num))
    number.close()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sever\pythonProject\text editor.py", line 16, in <module>
    num = int(num)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

im not sure how ton read the file and set it as variable

i couldn't really find simple answer

----------------------------------UPDATE------------------------------------

i wanted to do an append spam proggram to "employess.txt" what spams bot#(num)

i don't wanty it to reset the number when rerunning so it can continue where left off

so i decided to store the variable to an external source

ps. i also tried this

```
while True:
employee_file = open("employess.txt", "w")

employee_file.write("\nbot #" + str(num))

employee_file.close()

number = open("var.txt", "w")

num = int(num)

num += 1

employee_file.write(str(num))

number.close()
though it gave an error again:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sever\pythonProject\text editor.py", line 18, in <module>
    num = int(num)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: The issue with your code is given in the traceback.

Comment: Is there a reason you are storing values in a txt file? What pigeonburger states is correct, when you use readlines the file is returned as a list which causes int(num) to fail. Try printing num first, and  visualise what you need to store as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not clear to me what you are asking, and regardless of what is wrong with your actual code, here is a minimal example of how to implement e.g. a persistent number (stored in a file) that you can then use at your discretion.

```
import pickle
import os

state_file = "number.pickle"

if os.path.exists(state_file):
    with open(state_file, 'rb') as sf:
        persistent_number = pickle.load(sf)
else:
    persistent_number = 0
    
for _ in range(5):
    print(persistent_number) # 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 on first execution 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 on second and so on
    persistent_number += 1
    with open(state_file, 'wb') as sf:
        pickle.dump(persistent_number, sf)
```